# How to debug an electron app main process step by step?

Tags: javascript, debugging, electron

I have tried devtron (it give lot of tools to inspect but does not let you step by step debug the electron app.)

Also I have tried electron-inspector along with electron-inspector.

With the release of new version electron. electron-inspector rebuild is breaking. I have raised the bug [here](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/9401#issuecomment-299790868)

Comment: I am talking about electron 1.6.7 here. There electron-inspector just not compiling for windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

Any other method with node-inspector or electron-inspector is not working for electron version 1.6.x.

After much research the only simple and out of the box way to debug electron application step by step is visual studio code, Just install it.

Create a folder .vscode in your source app directory 
Create a file launch.json and add

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Debug Main Process",
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
      "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/.bin/electron.cmd",
      "program": "${workspaceRoot}/main.js"
    }
  ]
}
```

Press F5 or (Debug --> Start debugging). Your break point will hit.

steps copied from 
https://electron.atom.io/docs/tutorial/debugging-main-process-vscode/